# QML Gauge how to make initial value?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make Gauge's indicator start from 0, not from -5000. I managed to make it start from 0 to 5000. But as soon as I set any negative value, the indicator is not displayed. Help me please.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras.Private 1.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtCharts 2.3

Window {
    id: winapp
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 630
    color: "#1b2153"
    title: qsTr("FirstProject")

    Gauge {
        id: gauge1
        x: 20
        y: 53
        width: 44
        height: 547
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 30
        value: 1246
        minimumValue: -5000
        maximumValue: 5000
        tickmarkStepSize: 500
        formatValue: function(value) {
            return value.toFixed(0);
        }
        property double minBarValue: 0
        style: GaugeStyle{
            valueBar: Item {
                 implicitWidth: 16
                 Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: (gauge1.value === gauge1.minimumValue) ? 0 : parent.height /     (gauge1.value - gauge1.minimumValue) * (gauge1.value - gauge1.minBarValue)
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

[indicator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkvKt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that when values are negative, the calculated gauge height becomes negative. That is why no gauge is visible. Accounting for that can be achieved fairly easy like this for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras.Private 1.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtCharts 2.3

Window {
    id: winapp
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 630
    color: "#1b2153"
    title: qsTr("FirstProject")

    Gauge {
        id: gauge1
        x: 20
        y: 53
        width: 44
        height: 547
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 30
        value: 500
        minimumValue: -5000
        maximumValue: 5000
        tickmarkStepSize: 500
        formatValue: function(value) {
            return value.toFixed(0);
        }
        property double minBarValue: 0
        style: GaugeStyle{
            valueBar: Item {
                 implicitWidth: 16
                 Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: {
                        var maxSpan = Math.abs(gauge1.maximumValue) + Math.abs(gauge1.minimumValue)
                        var fill = Math.abs(gauge1.value)
                        var fillPercent = fill/maxSpan

                        var fillHeight = gauge1.height * fillPercent
                        return fillHeight - fillHeight/50
                    }
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        if (gauge1.value < 0) {
                            y = -height
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But there is one bug that appears: when you set value: -4999 or -5000, the indicator disappears

Comment: I updated the answer to fix the bug. I had to change the formula for the height a bit

Comment: THANKS you so much)

Comment: no problem. Consider accepting the answer if it solves the issue!